# How to merge usernames from another table to a single column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table **users**:

```
user_id | user_name
1       | John
2       | Ann
3       | Max
4       | James
```

and **groups**:

```
group_id | group_name
1        | Coders
2        | Music Fans
3        | Car Owners
```

There is also a third table **users_to_groups** which contains references between users and groups. Each group can contain multiple users.

```
id | user_id | group_id
```

How to het the list of all groups showing in rows the **group name and list of all users in it** like so:

```
id | group_name | listofusers
1  | Music Fans | John, Ann, James, Max
2  | Car Owners | John, Ann
3  | Coders     | Max, Ann
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Use `string_agg()`

```
select g.group_id, 
       g.group_name, 
       string_agg(u.user_name, ', ' order by u.user_name) as listofusers
from groups g 
  join users_to_groups utg on utg.group_id = g.group_id
  join users u on u.user_id = utg.user_id
group by g.group_id, g.group_name
order by g.group_id;
```